# Is there anything we can use doNotRemoveChild() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this `if` condition.

```
if(something === true) {
element.removeChild(element.lastChild)
} else {
element.doNotRemoveChild(element.lastChild)
}
```

if the condition is `true` , I want to remove child, else I don't want to remove child.

I know we don't have anything like `doNotRemoveChild()` in javascript, so, how 
can I do that.

Comment: Just leave the `else { }` clause out completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do anything in the else clause. Imagine your condition: if something is true, remove element nodes, if not, what do I want to do? Maybe you want to do something there, and maybe not. If you do not want to do anything, you don`t even need to write an else condition, they are not mandatory.

Maybe you should take a quick look about how if/else statements work in javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

And it would also be nice to take a look on the basics. Study what conditional statements are in algorithms: https://medium.com/@seanguthrie/conditionals-and-how-they-are-used-in-algorithms-9c98d35b57c

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just leave out the else.

```
if(something === true) {
    element.removeChild(element.lastChild)
}
```

That's it. That's what `if` does: if the condition isn't fulfilled, then the instructions under the `if` aren't executed.